# Encoding issue in the database - PHP

Tags: php, encoding

I have created a configuration file, which I include in each file created. This configuration file need to use for connect to the database without declaring it in each file. The problem is that when I pass the data into a table using a query, the encoding is corrupted. I have seen several online solutions, but there would be a way to integrate the fix in the configuration file? In this way do not have to set the type of coding before each query.
If I insert: "This is a test", is entered in the database as: 
"This Ã¨  a test".

This is my configuration file

```
define("HOST", "localhost");
define("USER", "root");
define("DATABASE", "test");
define("PASSWORD", "");
define("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); #> you can do something like that?
```

Comment: Those `define`s in themselves don't do anything. You need actual code which actually establishes the connection, and in that code you need to set the connection encoding. That's where you need to write `SET NAMES...` or whatever is more appropriate for your database API. Yes, you can use a `define` to define that constant here, but this won't execute any code.

Answer (score 1):

Just run the query SET NAMES 'UTF8'; in class constructor after connection to database is made. And yet if you still somewhere have problem with encoding, write a function which runs set names query, so you can easily call it whenever you need.

Answer (score 0):

do u have unicode characters in your table?
"SET NAMES 'utf8'" is needed whenever you want to send data to the server having characters that cannot be represented in pure ASCII, like 'ñ' or 'ö'.

That if the MySQL instance is not configured to expect UTF-8 encoding by default from client connections (many are, depending on your location and platform.)

Read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html in case you aren't aware how Unicode works.

If u're not sure, try removing the last line from your config file and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that you need to run this query. However it's not a very good idea to put query into define and also this define doesn't have any name in the code you showed us.

So you could do it this way:

```
define("DB_ENCODING", 'utf8');
```

and then after connecting with your database run query:

```
"SET NAMES '".DB_ENCODING."'"
```

However it's still not the best option. If you use mysqli for instance you can use `mysqli_set_charset()` instead so in fact you could use:

```
mysqli_set_charset($con, DB_ENCODING);
```

Comment: This is the correct sintax?
"SET NAMES '" .DB_ENCODING. " ' INSERT INTO test (name, id, user) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?)"

Comment: No, you should run first only SET NAMES query just once. And then INSERT INTO (not in the same query). So first `"SET NAMES '".DB_ENCODING."'"` and then `INSERT INTO test (name, id, user) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`

Comment: Ok mysqli_set_charset($con, DB_ENCODING); function, but i get this error: Notice: Undefined variable and Warning: mysqli_set_charset() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Comment: You need to put as first parameter link that is returned by `mysqli_connect()`. Please look at http://php.net//manual/pl/mysqli.set-charset.php